# Get id of item clicked and use it for creating dynamic url in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, dynamic-routing

I have a vue bootstrap table displaying, in each row, few properties of objects of an array (got through an api call with axios).

Every row has a button that should redirect me to a detail page, with more properties of that object, plus a map.

I was thinking to make a function to get the property id of the object contained in the clicked row, but I'm not sure on how to do it. I need the id to use it in the last part of the api call.

The store is structured so that I have a module for the user and another one for these objects (activities). In these modules I deal with state, actions and mutations. A separate file handles the getters. As these activities will be modified, I need to save their state too.

I will also need to be able to easily access all the properties of the single object (not only the ones shown in the table row) from other components.

I'm getting very confused.

Here the code:

Table with all the activities:

```
<b-table
  responsive
  :fields="fields"
  :items="activity"
>
  <template
    slot="actions"
  >
    <b-button
      v-b-tooltip.hover
      title="Mostra dettagli"
      variant="info"
      class="px-3"
      @click="goToActivityDetail"
    >
      <span class="svg-container">
        <svg-icon icon-class="search"/>
      </span>
    </b-button>     
  </template>       
</b-table>
```

In the script:

```
export default {
name: 'AllActivities',
data() {
  return {
    fields: [
      { key: 'activity.activityName', label: 'Activity', _showDetails: true},
      { key: 'related_activity', label: 'Related activity', _showDetails: true},
      { key: 'start', label: 'Start', _showDetails: true },
      { key: 'end', label: 'End', _showDetails: true },
      { key: 'travel_mode', label: 'Travel mode', _showDetails: true },
      { key: 'actions', label: '' }
    ],
    activity: [],
    methods: {
      getIdActivity(){
       **?? how to get it ??**
      },
      goToActivityDetail() {
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'activityDetail'
        })
      }
    }
```

```
goToActivityDetail()
```

obviously does not work, in the console:

```
- [vue-router] missing param for named route "activityDetail": Expected "activityId" to be defined
- [vue-router] missing param for redirect route with path "/see-all-activities/:activityId": Expected "activityId" to be defined)
```

In the getters file I have:

```
const getters = {
  sidebar: state => state.app.sidebar,
  device: state => state.app.device,
  token: state => state.user.token
}
export default getters
```

So here I will need to have something like:

```
activityId: state => state.activity.activityId
```

Which is coming from activity.js, which is:

```
import {
  getActivityId
} from '@/components/AllActivities'

const state = {
  activityId: getActivityId()
}

const mutations = {
  SET_ACTIVITY_ID: (state, activityId) => {
    state.activityId = activityId
  }
}

const actions = {
  setActivityId({
    commit
  }) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      commit('SET_ACTIVITY_ID', '')
      resolve()
    })
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

IF this is right, what is left is the function to get the id of the object contained in the table row clicked.
Also, how to write that activity id in the api call (axios)?
Now I have:

```
export function getSingleActivity() {
  return request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/user_activity/:activityId',
    method: 'get'
  })
}
```

But I am not sure if that's correct.
Also, how to access the other properties (to be displayed in the detailActivity page)? 
This will be made of a list of some properties (probably a stacked table component) and a map component, so I will need to access the properties in both these components.
I hope I've been clear enough,
thank you.

Comment: I just noticed the code I wrote is giving this error: ```Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _AllActivities.getActivityId) is not a function``` How is that? It is indeed a function

Comment: I am very confused, I see in the state I am just saving the activityId but I need to save the whole activity object, with all the properties in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was dead simple. I post how to solve it in case someone else get stuck on this too.
I added a slot scope to the template that contains the button:

```
<template
        slot="actions"
        slot-scope="data"
      >
```

Then I added the single activity (following the vue bootstrap markup data.item)  as parameter to the button click

```
@click="goToDetailActivity(data.item)"
```

And the function called by the click became:

```
goToDetailActivity(activity) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'DettaglioAttivita',
        params: { activityId: activity.id }
      })
    }
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning is you're using vuex. If I understand correctly you want to get the property read from vuex?

To read a property from vuex you can eather use this.$store.getters.activity
Or use mapGetter.

Read the following page https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Also you have to set the param when you do a router.push

```
router.push({ name: 'activity', params: { id: activityId } })
```

Comment: Yes, I added the tag for vuex, thanks for pointing it. I will try what you suggested, thank you.